# Find AWS web service endpoint IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I’m trying to access the AWS KMS from my on-premise network and all outbound traffic are blocked by the firewall.
Cisco firewall cannot use URLs, so I’m not able to use the kms..aws.com endpoint.

How to find the IP of this service and is this IP dynamic?

Comment: You should either use AWS Direct Connect or AWS Site-to-Site VPN

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to know the CIDRs of AWS KMS so that they can be whitelisted, or are you wanting to send the traffic via some different network connection?

Comment: I just want to whitelisted the CIDR for this URL - kms.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com. I got an IP range by ping to the URL and it seems 54.240.255.255/16. Is this is the correct way to get an IP? I can't find any documentation in AWS

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the AWS team and They said that there are no IPs dedicated for the KMS services so I have used all IPs for my region which has in the [Ip_range.json](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjLk7rH-6brAhUxnOAKHXb1C7sQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2Fgeneral%2Flatest%2Fgr%2Faws-ip-ranges.html&usg=AOvVaw3Oky2K6tQM5wxq40Lh0ROA) file after exclude the IPs that dedicated to the other services like EC2, S3 and etc.